# Calling render before all js files are loaded so the owl carousel is not working

Tags: reactjs, carousel, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am loading all JS files using SPComponentLoader in ts file and I am using await for each load call.

Even then when I debug my code I observed it goes to render() in .tsx in between, executes that and after returning it will load the next JS file. Following is my code:

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i309B.png)

I am calling this function in onInit():

`public async onInit(): Promise {

```
this.loadCSS();

this.loadScripts();
```

}`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `SPComponentLoader`, but I think `Promise.all` will be more readable than writing `await` 6 times. `then` methods and `return` statement can be removed too.

Comment: Also, you should `await` your `this.loadScripts()`

Comment: Can you give an example for promise.all? I have tried that but that didn't work, I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: Instead of `await f(); await f(); await f();`, do `await Promise.all([f(), f(), f()]);` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all))

Comment: That didn't work, showing same behavior.

Comment: Did you `await` your `this.loadScripts()` too?

Comment: Yes I did. Do we have some other way to load scripts from cdn but in sequence?